# How to self revoke delegate of a nft using revoke function of Metaplex?

Tags: web3.js, metaplex, metaplex-js

Using **approve** function of metaplex I had transferred the delegate of a nft to another wallet.
How can I use the revoke function so that the second wallet can self revoke itself as the delegate without the signature of the nft holding wallet.

This is what I tried, here secondWalletKey is the keypair of the current delegate and walletId is the publicKey of the nft holder.

```
          const nftOrSft = {
            address: new PublicKey(nftMint),
            tokenStandard: 0,
          };

            const revokeTxnBuilder = metaplex
              .nfts()
              .builders()
              .revoke({
                nftOrSft,
                authority: {
                  __kind: "self",
                  delegate: secondWalletKey,
                },
                delegate: {
                  type: "StandardV1",
                  owner: walletId,
                  delegate: secondWalletKey.publicKey,
                },
              });
```

But this gives me the error **Invalid owner**. Any idea as to how to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metaplex divides its many delegate variants into two classes: some are considered `token delegates` while the rest are considered `metadata delegates`. According to the metaplex [docs](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js/blob/main/README.md#revoke), self-revoke only works for metadata delegates.

The `Standard` variant belongs to the token-delegate class and therefore doesn't support self-revokes.